# Tensorflow upsample tensor of arbitrary size

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say I have a tensor with shape

```
[d0, d1,.., dn]
```

Is it possible to create a function that will up-sample only a certain dimensions `k` times? 
An example

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

if I apply it for dimension `2` with repetition factor `3`

```
[[1,1,1,2,2,2],[3,3,3,4,4,4]]
```

I know there's an `tf.image.resize` but it requires a tensor of a certain shape.

Answer (score 1):

How about `tf.concat`?

This is what I think: if the input's shape is [d1, d2, ..., dn], then output's shape should be [d1, d2, ..., dn*3]. If I am right, the code below may solve your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def repetition(a, factor):
    # get a's shape as a list
    shape = a.get_shape().as_list()
    concat_shape = shape + [1]

    # new shape
    shape[-1] *= factor

    a = tf.reshape(a, concat_shape)
    b = tf.reshape(tf.concat([a] * factor, -1), shape)

    return b

d1 = 2
d2 = 3
d3 = 4

np_a = np.random.rand(d1, d2, d3)
a = tf.constant(np_a)

b = repetition(a, 3)


sess = tf.Session()

print np_a
print sess.run(b)
```

The key is that `tf.concat` can indicate which axis it will concatenate the tensor.

Comment: could you implement it in a common way? It should accept dimensions to extend and factor

Comment: I have edited my answer. For most cases, you can use `a.get_shape().as_list()` to get the shape of a tensor.

Comment: It doesn't support dynamic size, and only the last dimension will be extended